# How to copy rgb from intellij color picker?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut, color-picker

Is there any way to copy three integer (not hex) `rgb` values in one time from `intelij` idea color picker?

Answer (score 0):

When you open a color picker, RGB value is usually preselected, so it's enough to hit `Ctrl+C` to copy it to clipboard:

[image]

Comment: That es explicitly not the question. He asked how to get the RGB value, NOT the HEX value.